# List not clearing when used in certain part of state machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a turn-based battle system and something is puzzling me right now. I've been able to fix the issue, however, I have NO IDEA as to why one way works and the other doesn't.

This is the block of code :

```
foreach (GameObject wrapper in wrappers) { 
    Destroy(wrapper);
}
wrappers.Clear();
```

I should also mention that I'm using unity, which locks me in C#4 (I'm aware they released an experimental support for C#6 but I'm having enough trouble right now, without adding unstable features)

So I have a State Machine for the GUI placed in the Update() function.

```
switch(heroInputState) {
            case HeroGUI.ACTIVATE: {
                    if(heroesToManage.Count > 0) {
                        actionPanel.SetActive(true);
                        choiceMade = false;
                        currentIndex = 0;
                        HighlightText(actions[currentIndex]);
                        spellBook.AddRange(heroesToManage[0].GetComponent<HeroStateMachine>().hero.spellBook);

                        heroInputState = HeroGUI.SELECT_COMMAND;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            case HeroGUI.SELECT_COMMAND: {

                    ////
                    //The code works when placed here
                    ////

                    ChooseAction(actions, actions);    //This simply allows me to move the cursor in the actionMenu by highlighting the current index of the "actions" list. When I press the E key, the choice is made.

                    actionType = CheckAction();

                    if (choiceMade) {
                        switch(actionType) {
                            case "Magic": {
                                    CreateSubMenuRows();       //This is the problem function
                                    break;
                            }

                            default: {
                                    heroInputState = HeroGUI.SELECT_TARGET;    //The next state in the state machine, not relevant to this question
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
             }
}

private void CreateSubMenuRows() {

    int rowCount = 0;

    ////
    //But isn't working here
    ////

    //Instantiate a new prefab holding 3 "namePlate" when the spell name and cost will appear
    while(rowCount < Mathf.CeilToInt((float)spellBook.Count / 3)) {
        GameObject newHorizontalWrapper = Instantiate(horizontalWrapper, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        newHorizontalWrapper.transform.SetParent(verticalWrapper.transform, false);
        wrappers.Add(newHorizontalWrapper);          

        rowCount++;
    }

    SortTextElements();    //This takes all <Text> elements in scene and sort them into two list used to manipulate the color of those elements

    numberOfRows = rowCount;
}
```

So this whole thing works on the first pass, I can select the action, the spell, and process the action. I also clear the List of Text elements in the last state of the machine since it depends on the number of spells in the current heroesToManage's spellBook.

When hero's turn comeback, the list shows 0 element, until I get to the CreateSubMenuRows function once again... In my case, there are 6 spells, meaning that it should have only 6 elements for each SpellName... However, if the block of code is placed at the start of the CreateSubMenuRows function, for some exotic reason, it finds 12 Text elements (6 of which have been destroyed and are now showing as missing), as if the list didn't clear the first time, even if it DOES show 0 element in the inspector until that point, the wrappers have been destroyed and the list of wrappers has been cleared... then I get a MissingReferenceException since it tries to load the destroyed Text element...

After fiddling for quite a while, I tried to move the destroy loop BEFORE the if statement and strangely, everything now works as intended. However, since I want to learn, I need to understand why exactly this thing isn't working when it's after the if statement...

**Sorry if it seems a bit messy, I'm still learning how to write clean code. Also, since this thing is 500 lines long, which would be way to many lines to post here, it can seem like a lot is missing but I can assure you that everything related is there**

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console when you place your code inside `CreateSubMenuRows()` ?

Comment: Wow... I wrote all of this and never even added the error I got... sorry for that. I get a MissingReferenceException because I have 12 Text elements but 6 have been destroyed so the Class isn't finding them. It seems like the second time it Sort the Text elements, the previous six are still there, even though the list has been cleared. I assume that since I'm destroying the wrappers first and then creating new ones, there should be only 6 Text elements found...

Comment: Where is that `wrappers` container defined? Is it a member variable of the MonoBehaviour class?

Comment: The wrappers List is defined as a new public List<GameObject> in the BattleStateMachine Class, which derives from MonoBehaviour. Is this what you meant?